How to use emailjs in a html component of form.io
In a self-hosted form.io install
I am trying to set up a emailjs form in a form.io HTML component.
I can not get it to send emails. I get no js console error, and no js logging happens either.
All the IDs and public key are correct.
If I modify this a bit, I can get it to work in a Google sheet modal
Can anyone see what the issue is?
Thanks
<div class="container">
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
    <div class="card card-body">
        <form id="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="from_name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize EmailJS (Make sure your EmailJS user ID is correct)
    emailjs.init("XXX"); 

    // Wait for Form.io to render the component
    Formio.events.on('formReady', function(form) { 
        var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

        myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var templateParams = {
                to_name: 'Recipient Name', // Replace with the recipient's name
                from_name: document.getElementById('from_name').value,
                message_html: document.getElementById('message').value
            };

            emailjs.send("service_XXX","template_XXX", templateParams) 
                .then(function(response) {
                    alert('Email sent successfully!');
                    myForm.reset(); 
                }, function(error) {
                    alert('Email failed to send. Please try again later.');
                });
        });
    });
</script>

